# Stop PhpStorm from correcting my code when I add PHPDoc to method

Tags: php, phpstorm

Okay, so I didn't have any issues with PhpStorm for over a year that I haven't solved by myself with a help of google and searching over the internet for solutions. But I came up with a thing that I couldn't find fix.

Suddenly my PhpStorm started acting uncommon. I have a method inside a class and when I want to add PHPDoc above that method with typing `/** <enter>`, it adds correctly, but also it corrects my code everywhere in that file. Mostly the lines where I have `list()` function, it corrects it just as simple array `[$var, $var2, ...]`.

Also at the same time I noticed that it corrects my view files (.html) and it adds one extra empty line at the end. I couldn't notice at what point it adds it, but when I try to remove it, he just keeps adding it back. The only way I can wayback that corrections is when I do git rollback for that file.

How to stop these two actions?

Comment: Seems odd. I don't seem to think of a setting that would do that upon adding comments. Do you happen to have any plugins such as [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) installed? Also what do you mean about HTML files? What action triggers the reformatting for them?

Comment: What's your IDE version exactly? `list(...) -> [...]` formatting has been fixed in 2019.3.1

Comment: @jelo, no I don't have any plugins installed
LazyOne, I had 2019.3 but after I saw your message I updated to 2019.3.1 but issue still persists

Comment: @MiomirPesic Look into "Smart Keys" in your IDE settings just in case (though, still, dunno which one could go that far). Otherwise, I'd [create an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) (unless you can find one), preferably with some kind of small video showcasing what's happening (or, at least, an example of a small source file before and after your doc block), plus all the relevant information (IDE version and the likes).

Comment: @Jeto, I changed the scheme in coding style preferences and now everything looks okay. But still I'm confused what went suddenly wrong. I was using same custom coding style almost a year